# Callback from client-side not working

Tags: php, jquery, html, post

I have html files clientside (part of a cross-platform app) that go out to the php file and need to get a varible or string back, it is correctly posting the data but not recieving it back.

This is triggered on submit (client side .html):

```
 var $form = $( this ),
         $submit = $form.find( 'button[type="submit"]' ),
         username_value = $form.find( 'input[name="username"]' ).val(),
         password_value = $form.find( 'input[name="password"]' ).val(),

         url =  $form.attr('action');

     /* Send the data using post */

      $.post(url, {username: username_value, password: password_value},function (data) {

        alert(data);
    });
```

this is the php file:

```
<?php
$username   = $_POST['username'];
$password   = $_POST['password'];

$DBusername = 'root';
$DBpassword = '';
$project = mysql_connect('localhost',$DBusername, $DBpassword);

mysql_select_db('PickMeUpDatabase', $project);

$sql="SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' and password='$password'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

$count=mysql_num_rows($result);


if($count==1){
echo 'console.log("hi");'; 
        $message = "saved successfully";
        echo $message;
}
else
{
    $sql = "Insert into users Values('me','myself','I','".$username."','Irene')";
mysql_query($sql);
        echo "Helooo";
}
    ?>
```

I know the php file doesnt really make sense at this point I changed a lot for debugging, but the mysql query in the "else" statement is being passed and added to the database but the echo right below it isnt being returned to where it will be alerted in the html. In fact I can change the alert in the html to alert anything and it wont happen.

Comment: Have you tried using Firebug's console to check the response of your Ajax call?

Comment: Trying that now, Ill update with the response

Comment: Maybe $form.find returns an array, so you'd need to select the first element.

Comment: Well the form succefully posts the information needed but Firebug does show the "Response" tab as blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There could be a lot of reasons why this is happening.

Do you have error reporting turned on? If not, put this after the php delimiter:

```
ini_set( "display_errors", true );
```

Also, is the data being sent cross domain? Put this after the above line,

```
 header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

Now, It might be POSTing, but that doesn't necessarily mean the data is usable on the server end. Whenver I use the post() function in JQuery, I prefer strings for the data parameters. It looks like a few variables are undefined, too.

So I would rewrite it this way:

```
 var $form = $( this ),
         $submit = $form.find( 'button[type="submit"]' ),
         username_value = $form.find( 'input[name="username"]' ).val(),
         password_value = $form.find( 'input[name="password"]' ).val(),

          /* Turn the variables into strings- for simplicity! */
         url =  "http://localhost/location/of/php_file.php";


      var data='username='+username_value+'&password='+password_value;
      $.post(url, data, function (data) {

        alert(data);
    });
```

That should clean it up a little more.

Comment: Ok I changed it to look like that, it appeared to have no affect. POST is still going out according to firebug and the mysql query still running but no responses.
Also I dont think I added that error reporter correctly, where exactly should it go, and where would it output errors?

Comment: Put the error reporting in the first line in PHP file. The output will be in the alert box, triggered by alert(data) in the jquery function.

Comment: Also, if all else fails, then it is MYSQL error failing silently.

Comment: Ok yah thats where I put it but the problem is the alert box isnt triggering. Ive also taken out the mysql code and it still does not alert

Comment: It will always trigger, data or no data- Empty box, worse case scenario. Are you sure there isn't a JS error somewhere in there?

Comment: Im recieving this error but Im not sure what it is.
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost/login.php. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Comment: Great! That's what you're looking for. The data isn't posting to the right place. Updating answer.

Comment: That seemed promising but it just gave the same error with the new URL
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost/location/of/php_file.php. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Comment: did you add header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); to your php file?

Comment: Like so?:
    `<?php 
 ini_set( "display_errors", true );
 header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
 ...`

Comment: Ok I got it!! I have noooo idea what finally fixed it but it had to be something you said so thank you very much!